# Use Windows Credentials for FTP connection in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, kerberos

A question related to [FTP Login using Windows Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319752/ftp-login-using-windows-credentials) but on this thread the discussion went in another direction.

The [CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx) doesn't work with FTP. Is there a way to use the Windows user account as the credentials for an FTP connection in C#?

If the FTP server could accept Kerberos tickets for authentication, how could you send it using the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class ?

Answer (score 0):

Below are 3 ways to login to FTP, but they still require user input for either the username or password:

```
    System.Net.FtpWebRequest f = System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://somewhere.com")) as System.Net.FtpWebRequest;
    if (f != null)
    {
        f.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        f.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        f.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, "password");
    }
```

The last one takes the windows username, but still requires some way to obtain the password from the user.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to pass the Kerberos ticket of the current logged user to the FTP login

Comment: Apart from going low-level, I don't see how it can be done with the currently available classes. Even if we use some third party or open source library, they'll still have to go low-level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what credentials are you talking about.

If you are talking about the FTP's username and password then:

```
R.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
```

Should do the trick.

If you are asking about Proxy credentials that are used by windows to go over a proxy the same way Explorer or Firefox pass the proxy then:

```
R.Proxy = new WebProxy();
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: I want to use the current logged user credentials